# Can I use "portion" as a verb?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

I'm trying to decide if the following is a correct way to use the word portion:

"These are the sites with the least published information and did not portion a significant part of the study."

In this sentence, can portion be used to mean "comprise" or "amount to", as in the sites do not comprise a significant portion of the data?

Hope I'm clear,
thanks.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/PORTION: This link supports the use of portion as verb.

Comment: I've only seen "portion" as a verb used to mean "divide into portions".